# Camera image from FileProvider Uri only displaying for first time

Tags: android, android-camera, android-jetpack-compose, android-fileprovider, android-compose-image

My Jetpack Compose camera app is targeting API Level 32 and is being tested on an Android 11 phone. I'm generating a `Uri` with `FileProvider` to take a photo with the stock camera app. Logcat shows the `Uri` every time I snap a picture, but the image is displayed in the UI only for the first time. Subsequent camera snapshots don't show the image although the `Uri` is displayed in Logcat. And exiting the app with a back button click and then opening the app to take a snapshot, again, only works for the first time. How can I fix this issue?

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.testsoft.camtest">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Camtest"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Camtest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**File Paths XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.testsoft.camtest/files/Pictures"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_debug_images"
        path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.testsoft.camtest/files/Pictures/"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_root_images"
        path="/"/>
</paths>
```

**MainScreen Composable**

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var hasImage by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var imageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    var grantCameraState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        )
    }

    val cameraPermissionlauncher: ManagedActivityResultLauncher<String, Boolean> =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
            grantCameraState = it
        }

    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success ->
        Log.i("UriContent@Snapshot", imageUri.toString())
        hasImage = success
    }

    Column {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            onClick = {
            if (grantCameraState) {
                val uri = getCamImageUri(context)
                imageUri = uri
                cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
            } else {
                cameraPermissionlauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Take photo")
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.width(10.dp))

        if(hasImage && imageUri != null){
            Log.i("UriContent@Render", imageUri.toString())

            AsyncImage(
                imageUri,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )

        /*
            //Also tried this but had the same issue:

            Image(
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageUri),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        */
        }
    }
}

fun getCamImageUri(context: Context): Uri? {
    var uri: Uri? = null
    val file = createImageFile(context)
    try {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.testsoft.camtest.fileprovider", file)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Error: ${e.message}")
    }
    return uri
}

private fun createImageFile(context: Context) : File {
    val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val imageDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "Camtest_Image_${timestamp}",
        ".jpg",
        imageDirectory
    )
}
```

**Logcat Output**

```
I/UriContent@Snapshot: content://com.testsoft.camtest.fileprovider/my_root_images/Pictures/Camtest_Image_20220702_1002472475660413794636578.jpg

I/UriContent@Render: content://com.testsoft.camtest.fileprovider/my_root_images/Pictures/Camtest_Image_20220702_1002472475660413794636578.jpg
```

**Logcat message with subsequent camera launch**

```
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. After debugging the app, I discovered that I needed to set the `hasImage` state variable to `false` in the `Take photo` button's `onclick` logic like below:

```
 Button(
    modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    onClick = {
        if (grantCameraState) {
           val uri = getCamImageUri(context)
           imageUri = uri

           // Set it to false here
           hasImage = false

           cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
        } else {
        cameraPermissionlauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
       }
  }) {
    Text(text = "Take photo")
 }
```